# randomly opening of processes connecting to the internet

Tags: firefox

```
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/13281/1000 0.358789    8.26699
192.168.1.100:37160-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37156-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37152-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37150-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37148-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37146-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37144-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37140-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37138-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37136-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37134-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37132-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37126-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37124-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37122-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37120-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
192.168.1.100:37116-172.217.23.228:443/0/0  0   0
unknown TCP/0/0 0   0
```

Is something wrong with that?

```
Refreshing:
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/13281/1000 0.304102    0.220703
/usr/sbin/NetworkManager/771/0  0   0
/usr/bin/python3/18616/0    0   0
/usr/lib/snapd/snapd/775/0  0   0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http/18009/104 0   0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http/18008/104 0   0
unknown TCP/0/0 0   0
```

what is this python3 and the http file i cant seem to open? (system freezes)

```
Refreshing:
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/13281/1000 2.22441 79.7977
192.168.1.100:41698-157.240.30.27:443/0/0   0   0
unknown TCP/0/0  0   0
```

Also, is facebook somehow working outside of firefox? how can i limit this?

Comment: 172.217.23.228 is a Google address. If you have Gmail open on a Firefox tab it will check your mail periodically. Business as usual.

Comment: The other IP address does belong to Facebook. If you want to know what process connects to it, do `ps aux | grep 41698` (probably a Firefox thread though).

Comment: Have you setup "Settings->Online accounts" for checking email, gdrive and facebook? Then it could be them. Also, then firefox connecting to huge site it open not the one connection, to download all css, images, fonts, etc faster.